# if statement not returning proper result

Tags: php

I have created a function that checks if the image is empty or image variable has no value or the image is not found then it returns default image, but on some products it gives results but not on all of them..

```
function image_check($image)
{
    $no_image = "noimagefound.jpg";
    if(isset($image) || !empty($image) || $image != " ")
    {
        if(file_exists('uploads/store/products/'.$image))
        {
            return 'uploads/store/products/'.$image;
        }
        else
        {
            return 'uploads/web_service/'.$no_image;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 'uploads/web_service/'.$no_image;
    }
}
```

Can anyone make it work properly? What am I missing?

Comment: This makes no sense... You use the `$image` value if it is empty or contains only a blank...

Comment: Try printing '$image' to ensure it contains what you expect.

Comment: Looks like you want `!empty($image) && $image != " "` for the condition

Comment: `if(!empty($image))` this much is sufficient

Comment: Sorry that was a typo during editing my code in stackoverflow

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and this `|| $image==" "` that checks if it's equal to a space; remove it `|| $image==""`

Comment: @RiggsFolly you've changed his logic with your rollback

Comment: Even at this statement `isset($image) || !empty($image) || $image!=""` me gets no results

Comment: @bcmcfc No I thought that you changed it

Comment: @bcmcfc His original code did not have a `!empty($image)` please dont edit the question to suggest corrections

Comment: @RiggsFolly His edit did - http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41470072/2 - he said in a comment he made an error copying it into SO. Clearly the OP's own edit is what he intended to put in the question.

Comment: I tried with `!empty()` and `!=""` but it didn't work so when I was copying my question here I accidently copied the question with older `if` statement

Comment: My sincere apology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function image_check($image)
{
    $no_image = "noimagefound.jpg";
    if( !empty($image) && file_exists('uploads/store/products/'.$image) )
    {
        return 'uploads/store/products/'.$image;
    }
    return 'uploads/web_service/'.$no_image;
}
```

As they pointed out in the comments, your condition failed because you were checking if it was empty, not if it wasn't empty.  isset() and !empty() are redundant in this case.

You also don't need all of those else checks.  Be careful complicating your code more than you need to.  You only need one check, if that fails, then return your `$no_image`.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much! I got it now! Appreciate this explanation

Comment: @Anant not really a loop hole because the file_exists call will fail...

Comment: @Devon  yes correct in this case, but sometimes its behave like loophole. +1

Comment: `&& file_exists()` will suffice I believe

Comment: @Alexu  as i said that it will work in this case but not in all cases